# Regex to find multiple repeating numbers separated by space

Tags: c#, regex

I tried a couple of things but none of them worked as expected. The aim is to detect *duplicate* house *numbers* behind the street.

As an example, this would be a correct entry:

`Randomstreet 33a`

or

`Randomstreet 45`

But sometimes there is (please, note number repetition)

`Randomstreet 33a 33a`

or

`Randomstreet 45 45`

So the rule would be that

> no two identical blocks of characters separated by a space may occur from the back

I have tried various simple patterns but it seems that I am already failing in understanding them.

Comment: when you share your regular expressions, we can help you understand what you did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If we can assume that the number (house number, apartment number etc.) must start from digits `1..9` and can end by English small case letters `a..z` then you can try matching *regular expression* pattern:

```
(?<number>[1-9][0-9]*[a-z]*)(?:\s+\k<number>)+
```

Pattern explained

```
(?<number>[1-9][0-9]*[a-z]*) - a group "number" which
                               starts from digit in 1..9 range
                               can followed by digits in 0..9 range
                               finally, can followed by letters in a..z range
          (?:\s+\k<number>)+ - the very same match "number" repeated 
                               one or more times separated by white spaces
```

Code:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpression;

...

string text = "Randomstreet 33a 33a or Randomstreet 45 45 apartment 14 14 14";

var result = Regex
  .Matches(text, @"(?<number>[1-9][0-9]*[a-z]*)(?:\s+\k<number>)+")
  .Select(match => match.Groups["number"].Value)
  .ToArray();

Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Output:

```
33a
45
14
```

Comment: `a-b` should have been `a-z`.

Comment: @InSync: Thank you! What a stupid error I've done ;)